# Quantum fluctuations in the early universe

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, cosmological-inflation

A Quanta Magazine [article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/the-origin-of-time-bootstrapped-from-fundamental-symmetries-20191029/) on the relationship between inflation and the large-scale structure of the universe mentions the relationship between the spatial distribution of galaxies and quantum fluctuations during inflation. It is said that (roughly speaking) galaxies are distributed according to the quantum fluctuations that took place in the early universe during inflation. In this case, the fluctuations themselves are described as the production of pairs of virtual particles.

But I was alarmed by this sentence: <... astronomical objects are not randomly strewn throughout space. Rather, spatial correlations between the positions of objects such as galaxies tell a detailed story of the ancient past>. What do you mean "not by randomly"? Quantum fluctuations are always a random process, which means that the distribution of density fluctuations in the early universe should have also been random. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Randomly drawn from a distribution which is not uniform.

Comment: @Connor Behan more details?